# Dependency Injection fix using Ninject?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-2

### **Question**

Do you have any other point that supports Ninject other then below mentioned two points?

============

### **Details**

1. We don't need to pass the instance to any constructor wherever we need Employee instance.
2. We may have a situation when two classes have same functions so using the common Interface for these classes.

### **Example Code**

```
class Sword : IWeapon
{
    public void Hit(string target) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Chopped {0} clean in half", target);
    }
}

class Shuriken : IWeapon
{
    public void Hit(string target)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Pierced {0}'s armor", target);
    }
}
```

Both are using same Interface.
This link says that we may have different classes, which have common Interface.

### **[Click here to check the link](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Dependency-Injection-By-Hand)**

But, in my case there in no such situation, where I have two classes using the common Interface

Using the **Ninject Dependency Resolver**, and using the below code, we can fix this issue

```
var kernel = new StandardKernel();
kernel.Bind<Practise.Models.IEmployee>().To<Practise.Models.Employee>();
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new NinjectDependencyResolver(kernel));
```

Using this code, I don't need to pass the Employee instance to any constructor.